# With pdflatex and the minted package, how do I eliminate whitespace and include entire document?

Tags: pdftex, input, minted

I'm using tex because it seems to be the most appropriate tool for my workflow...

I'm making posters to teach computer programming, these need to be full of syntax-highlighted code.  I have a directory of source code files and need to be able to run a script on those to convert them to a format that I can use in the page layout program Scribus.

PDFLATEX seems to be the appropriate tool for doing that but I have no experience with Latex prior to having fiddled with it now for several hours.

My example.tex looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usemintedstyle{monokai}

\begin{document}
\begin{LARGE}
  \inputminted{php}{example.php}
\end{LARGE}
\end{document}
```

And I generate a pdf simply with `pdflatex --shell-escape example.tex`.  This is really great because I have a folder full of files and can run a script to create pdfs of all of them, the pdfs are embedded in Scribus and when I make changes to the code I can simply run the script to update all the pdfs which get automatically updated in Scribus.  Yay!...except that I don't know Latex...

**The problem:**  there seems to be some default document size being applied.  It's way too big vertically, and too small horizontally so the code/content gets clipped off.

Ideally, the pdf document would be automatically sized according to the contents of the code without any empty margin space.  Currently I don't need any automatic line-wrapping, but at some point I imagine I would.

The question!...

**What's up with this sizing / margins / document size *stuff*?  How do I get rid of this huge empty margin and get the full contents of the code to appear?**

I've tried:

- changing `documentclass{}` to `minimal` (which requires removing `LARGE` and doesn't solve either problem) and `standalone` (which just breaks and says there's "perhaps a missing \item".
- doing stuff with geometry like `\usepackage[paperwidth=\maxdimen,paperheight=\maxdimen]{geometry}` but that renders a huuuge amount of white space surrounding the entire code (so all the code is visible and maybe I could run `pdfcrop` on it but I shouldn't need to right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default size of a page is normally letter or A4.  You can use geometry to reduce the page size but not with `\maxdimen` as this is the largest length TeX can handle.

With standalone you can use the `varwidth` option. But you must set the line width manually:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=4cm,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{minted}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usemintedstyle{monokai}

\begin{document}

  \inputminted[breaklines]{php}{example.php}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Adding [varwidth=#cm] before {standalone} gets this working in a manual way.  Is there any way to do that automatically?  It'd be nice if tex could calculate how wide the contents is and create the document to fit that...

Comment: As far as I could see minted gives back a box of width \linewidth, so ask the maintainer of minted.